# ODATA. Can't run BasicAuthentication module with WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, wcf

Can't run BasicAuthentication module on WCF Data Service, i have  HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

and config source showing error in "add name="BasicAuthenticationModule"" line

I used blogs.mdsn.microsoft topics for writing this authentication, also i enabled basicauthentication in my IIS local project and global config.

> Web.config

```
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">   
<add name="BasicAuthenticationModule" 
     type="Service.BasicAuthenticationModule"/> 
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"
  type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule,
Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

> Module and AuthenticationProvider

```
  public class BasicAuthenticationModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
       context.AuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(context_AuthenticateRequest);
    }

void context_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Unbox the application.
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;

    //Send to provider for authentication.
    if (!BasicAuthenticationProvider.Authenticate(application.Context))
    {
        application.Context.Response.Status = "401 Unauthorized";
        application.Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        application.Context.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
        application.CompleteRequest();
    }
}
public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}



   public class BasicAuthenticationProvider
{
    public static bool Authenticate(HttpContext context)
    {
        //This needs to be uncommented for live site.
        //This will reject the login when not using SSL.
        //if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection
        //    return false;
        //I only want to execute code for authorization requests.
        //if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Authorization"))
        //    return false;

        string authHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        IPrincipal principal;
        if (TryGetPrincipal(authHeader, out principal))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static string[] ParseAuthHeader(string authHeader)
    {
        // Check this is a Basic Auth header
        if (
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader) ||
            !authHeader.StartsWith("Basic")
            ) return null;

        // Pull out the Credentials with are separated by ':' and Base64 encoded
        string base64Credentials = authHeader.Substring(6);
        string[] credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
            Convert.FromBase64String(base64Credentials)
            ).Split(new char[] { ':' });

        if (credentials.Length != 2 ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[0]) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[0])
            ) return null;

        // Okay this is the credentials
        return credentials;
    }

    private static bool TryGetPrincipal(string authHeader, out IPrincipal principal)
    {
        var creds = ParseAuthHeader(authHeader);
        if (creds != null && TryGetPrincipal(creds, out principal))
            return true;

        principal = null;
        return false;
    }

    private static bool TryGetPrincipal(string[] creds, out IPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (creds[0] == "Administrator" && creds[1] == "SecurePassword")
        {
            principal = new GenericPrincipal(
               new GenericIdentity("Administrator"),
               new string[] { "Administrator", "User" }
            );
            return true;
        }
        else if (creds[0] == "JoeBlogs" && creds[1] == "Password")
        {
            principal = new GenericPrincipal(
               new GenericIdentity("JoeBlogs"),
               new string[] { "User" }
            );
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            principal = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```